# Is the Google Nexus S capable of reading the exFAT file format?

Tags: internal-storage, samsung-nexus-s

If I backup, reformat the internal memory "disk" of my Google Nexus One (running Android 2.3.4) into the exFAT format (for storage of file sizes over 4GB) and restore the contents, will it spasm and die or will it go on as if nothing had changed?

Comment: I just tried this on my HTC Desire HD. Android does not seem to support it. It doesn't report errors though. If you check the SD & phone storage size it says "not available" and if you try to snap a photo it just doesn't do it. But if you put the microSD back into your computer after doing that, Windows will report that the microSD card is not formatted, so Android seems to mess up the format.

Comment: Isn't it odd that the exFAT format, which was designed for mobile devices, isn't supported by a modern Linux-based OS such as Android? :-\

Comment: @aalaap exFAT is a filesystem from Microsoft, [which means you have to pay Microsoft to use it commercially.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Disadvantages) Linux itself has only beta state support of exFAT. But the times where Microsoft could just set the standards and collect money for it are thankfully over. If they just had released it license free and opened the specs we likely had a portable and wide spread filesystem for mobile storage/flash cards by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As reported and commented on by various users, there is no exFAT support built in to Android, so the Nexus S will not read the disk.